# переадресация адреса указателя

Tags: c++

1) `int k=0; int *ptr = &k;`

могу ли я искусственно дать указателю , адрес в другую ячейку памяти ?

приметно так `ptr = 0x10bac6138`;

2) как мне создать переменную , чтобы ее зона видимости была и в `main.cpp` и  `main.hpp`?

Comment: Прочтите про `extern variables`.

Comment: 1) запросто `ptr = (int*)0x10bac6138;` за риски писать не буду.

Comment: Два вопроса в одном топике, к сожалению, засоряют ресурс и усложняют поиск по нему. Разделите вопросы на два топика.

Comment: 2) если по правилам - обьявление из hpp будет видно в cpp, но при этом в cpp должен быть подключен hpp. Если не подключен- подключайте через include. Так же - читайте основы с

Answer (score 2):

Сослаться на произвольный адрес в памяти можно, однако вам должно быть доподлинно известно, что по этому адресу что-то есть.

То есть, этот адрес получен либо как часть блока адресов, который вернула функция выделения памяти, либо получен из операционной системы. Либо вы подсмотрели его в справочнике на то железо, которое исполняет вашу программу.

Если же адрес вы написали наобум, очень вероятно, что при разыменовании такого указателя, или обращении к нему, программа поведет себя непредсказуемо.